# I'm attempting to push JSON objects into an array every time a button is pressed and displayed the results

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So i'm attempting to generate a random selection from an array which a user can add to by pressing a button and i'm a bit confused on how to do it.The app is made in react and it's used movieDB's api to make a film search engine. This is what I attempted so far:

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './App';
import{ Button } from 'reactstrap'
import { AddToSelector } from './Components/AddToSelector.Component'
class MovieRow extends React.Component{

  addToFavourites = () =>
    {
      var arr = [];
      const movieRow = <AddToSelector key={this.props.movie.id} 
      movie={this.props.movie}/>
      console.log(this.props.movie.title);
      arr = arr.push(this.props.movie.id);

    } 

    pickRandom = (arr) =>
    {
       console.log(arr);  
    }

  render() {
        return (
        <div>

        <table key = {this.props.movie.id}>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <img alt="poster" src={this.props.movie.poster_src}/> 
          </td>
            <td>
            <p>{this.props.movie.title}</p>
            <p>{this.props.movie.overview}</p>
            <Button color="primary" onClick={this.addToFavourites}>Add</Button> 
            <Button color="primary" onClick={this.pickRandom}>Random</Button> 
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>



        </div>
        );
    }
}

export default MovieRow;
```

Comment: `var arr = [];` only exists inside that function, and is deleted from memory when the function has finished. Move the declaration outside your class to keep the variable in memory. Also `arr.push(...)` is enough, `arr = arr.push(...)` will overwrite the array with the length of the new array. Next you'll want to remove the `arr` parameter from `pickRandom` since it otherwise shadows the outer `arr`. You don't need it there anyway, and you aren't passing anything into it to boot when you call the function.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting there. You've got a few issues:

1. You're defining arr in addToFavourites, so every time it is called a new arr is created that's only available within that function. Essentially, you're creating the array, adding the item, and then it's tossed in the garbage.

   Since your MovieRow represents one movie, you're gonna want to have
   a wrapper component that maintains arr as part of its state. You'll
   also define addToFavourites there and then pass that down to each
   MovieRow component, making sure to pass at least the movie id so you
   know which movie to add to the favorites
2. I'm not sure what movieRow in addToFavorites does because you assign it and then never use it. Essentially here you're defining movieRow on the global window object the first time around and then reassigning that each time you click. This seems unnecessary.
3. You'll also want to move pickRandom to the parent component that maintains your favorite list.

Hopefully this gets you going in the right direction. Let me know if you have questions

Answer (score 0):

I think `state` is what you're probably looking for. You need to set initial array state in constructor, then update it in addToFavourites (using this.setState) and use updated state in pickRandom. Please consult [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should store the list of movies in you component state. Read more about the app state and components lifecycle in the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

```
class MovieRow extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
        this.state = {
            movies: []
        }
     }
}
```

Then in the method that is handling the click event in your Add button, you can use [setState()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) to update the state and then changes will be reflected in the template.

```
addToFavourites() {
  const newMovie = getMovie(); // I don't know where are you getting the movie, but you get the idea.
  this.setState((state) => {
    return { 
      movies: [...state.movies, newMovie] 
    }
  });
}
```

Then considering you have stored in the state an array of objects representing your movies. You should map that array to a list of components in the render function.

Example:

```
render() {
  return (
    this.state.movies.map((movie) => <MovieComponent key={movie.id} title={movie.title} />)
  )
}
```

Comment: Ok so i've done the first two steps but i'm a bit confused on the 3 piece of code, could you explain what you mean by mapping the array to a list of components? So far my array adds a movie to but it's still just one movie, which is the last one clicked so i'm a little stumped on how to approach it. Thanks a million for the answer!

Comment: If you are not familiar with array manipulation in Javascript, you should read more about it, there are plenty of tutorials, books, etc. The [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method creates a new array with the value returned in the function for every item in the array. In other words, we want to transform the raw data that you had from your .json into a list of React components to render in your template.

Comment: By the way, my answer is based on an array because I thought you wanted to display a list of movies but if you only want to show one movie, you could do it without an array.